# Float variable calculation using int error

Tags: c++

I run the following code:

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  int x=4,y=2,z=11;
  float p;
  p=7+z/y-x*2;
  cout<<p;
  return 0;
}
```

The x, y, z is declared as integer. Why the p get an int while p is declared as float?

Thanks.

Comment: Please put here the full code.

Comment: Put more details here

Comment: because bro you declare your input value in integer

Comment: I am not able to paste the code here as I am using a phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a and b are integers then result of a/b will always be integer, not float. Dividing result is just truncated to integer value and float part is thrown away.

In expression `7+z/y-x*2` only integer variables are used, that is why result is also integer.

As an option you can cast one of the operands on right side to float, then whole expression will be threated as float:

```
7+z/(float)y-x*2
```

Comment: But p is declared as float. It should be stored as float right?

Comment: At first, expression on right side of assignment operator is calculated. It has type of int. Then during assignment it's casted to float, but the original float part is missed during calculation.

Comment: But I still can't see the logic flow. It should be calculated in the way of float right?

Comment: See second part of my post. To achieve this you should cast one of operands to float: 7+z/(float)y-x*2

Comment: Re: "it's casted to float" -- there is no cast involved. The value is **converted** to float. A cast is something you write in your source code to tell the compiler to do a conversion.

Answer (score 0):

pls change your integer datatype to float so u got

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  float x=4,y=2,z=11;
  float p;
  p=7+z/y-x*2;
  cout<<p;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I know. But I just want to know the concept of the calculation.